# Notepad++ Find & Replace

Tags: replace, notepad++, addition

I need help with changing over 100 lines of code with this syntax:

```
Create3DTextLabel(text[], color, Float:X, Float:Y, Float:Z, Float:DrawDistance, virtualworld)
```

to this:

```
CreateDynamic3DTextLabel(text[], color, Float:x, Float:y, Float:z, Float:DrawDistance, INVALID_PLAYER_ID, INVALID_VEHICLE_ID, 0, virtualworld, -1, -1, 100.0);
```

Here is the example line:

```
Create3DTextLabel("Bussijaam (A 1, 2, X1, N1)",0x66CC00FF,1785.36, -1836.29, 14.50,30.0,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure what virtualworld is, I have assumed it is 0-1 flag and I have used following values for replace function:

Find what:

```
Create3DTextLabel\("(.*)",([\sx0-9A-F]+),([\s-0-9.]+),([\s-0-9.]+),([\s-0-9.]+),([\s-0-9.]+),([01]+)\);
```

Replace with:

```
CreateDynamic3DTextLabel("\1",\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,INVALID_PLAYER_ID,INVALID_VEHICLE_ID,0,\7,-1,-1,100.0);
```

Comment: Thank you, just the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+H or navigate to menubar>>Search>>Replace... menu
Type "Create3DTextLabel" in Find what field
and "CreateDynamic3DTextLabel" in Replace with field

uncheck "Match whole word only"
click replace all button

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that there are more parts that are different, also some of them change locations.